# Data recovery on a Samsung SV1203N HDD

Tags: windows, data-recovery, samsung

Let me start by saying that I am a beginner in Ubuntu, but pretty knowledgeable with Windows.

I am having a strange problem trying to recover data from a Samsung SV1203N HDD (120 GiB).
I have tried numerous things in both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (on a flash drive, an external HDD and a Live CD). This drive has some very important data on it and I am praying some of you Ubuntu geeks can help me get it back.

Here's my problem.
The HDD is clicking while I am booting, but it stops when I get into Ubuntu or Windows. It refuses to be detected in the bios, so I cant perform any tests on it. I have tried numerous things in both Windows (repair CD, Jumpers, etc.) and Ubuntu (Boot-Fix, GParted, Testdisk, Photorec, forcing a mount, etc.). But it all seems to lead me back to the fact that the drive is not being recognized in the BIOS. I've even tried chilling the drive in the fridge, which worked well for another drive I work on, and I recovered all of the data in Ubuntu flawlessly.

I am assuming that since the drive stops clicking when I get into the OS' that there is hope for recovery. I am going to try an IDE/SATA to USB cable, and replacing the Logic Board, but I want to exhaust all other possibilities before I do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the clicking is the drive trying to read, then it fails as denoted by the silence. This would be why it is not recognized by anything (BIOS, OS).

You may need to bring it to a recovery professional. Continuing to try and get it running could be damaging the platters/erasing data. Someone who recovers data professionally, should be able to get your data safely back to you.

EDIT - I also found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to recover the deleted data from android phone. Have a try.

1. Connect your Samsung and enable USB debugging.
2. Analyze your phone.
   After the USB debugging, reconnect your phone if you are asked to disconnect it during the setting. You need to bear in mind that your phone's battery is more than 20% charged, and then you can click "Start" to let the program analyze your Android phone.
3. Scan your Android for deleted data.
4. Preview and [recover data from Android](http://www.transfer-iphone-recovery.com/samsung-galaxy-data-recovery.html).

Hope you get your data back soon!